# Combining probe files in intermapper

Tags: python-3.x, snmp, pysnmp

I have two devices
      1. Device 1
      2. Device 2
 for now I have two separate probe files for both the devices since both follows different format in Intermapper status window. I want to combine them into a single probe file.

Solutions Tried:

1. Tried giving the following condition under **snmp-device-display** tag 
   ${EVAL: $DT == "Device 1"? "format for device 1" : $DT == "Device 2"? "format for device 2" : ""}

- The problem was, I was not able to give this particular stmt inside the string
  ${chartable: ##.## : $value1}
- The output of the EVAL conditions must be a string, since my format was too big (more than 255 char), it throwed me an exception. Rectified it by splitting the string and concatenating it.

Here is some sample code similar to the solution I have tried:

```
<snmp-device-variables>
        DT_,    1.3.6.1.4.1.44555.1.1.10.0, DEFAULT,    "dt"
        DT1VAL1_ 1.3.6.1.4.1.44555.1.1.10.1 DEFAULT,    "d1v1"
        DT1VAL2_ 1.3.6.1.4.1.44555.1.1.10.2 DEFAULT,    "d1v2"
        DT1VAL3_ 1.3.6.1.4.1.44555.1.1.10.3 DEFAULT,    "d1v3"
        DT1VAL4_ 1.3.6.1.4.1.44555.1.1.10.4 DEFAULT,    "d1v4"
        DT2VAL1_ 1.3.6.1.4.1.44555.1.1.11.1 DEFAULT,    "d1v1"
        DT2VAL2_ 1.3.6.1.4.1.44555.1.1.11.2 DEFAULT,    "d1v2"
        DT2VAL3_ 1.3.6.1.4.1.44555.1.1.11.3 DEFAULT,    "d1v3"
</snmp-device-variables>
        
        
<snmp-device-display>
        \0\ ${EVAL: $DT_=="device1" ? " \4\ DT1VAL1_:\0\ ${chartable: ##.## : $DT1VAL1_} \3G\Val1\M0\
                    \4\ DT1VAL2_:\0\ ${chartable: ##.## : $DT1VAL2_} \3G\Val2\M0\
                    \4\ DT1VAL3_:\0\ ${chartable: ##.## : $DT1VAL3_} \3G\Val3\M0\
                    \4\ DT1VAL4_:\0\ ${chartable: ##.## : $DT1VAL4_} \3G\Val4\M0\"
        : $DT_ == "device2" ? " \4\ DT2VAL1_:\0\ ${chartable: ##.## : $DT2VAL1_} \3G\Val2\M0\
                    \4\ DT2VALUE2_:\0\ ${chartable: ##.## : $DT2VAL2_} \3G\Val2\M0\
                    \4\ DT2VALUE3_:\0\ ${chartable: ##.## : $DT2VAL3_} \3G\Val3\M0\":""}
</snmp-device-display>
```

Kindly give me any other solution we can follow to combine probes.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing both the data and the code that you have written that produces your problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.

Comment: I have included a sample code in the above query